# Read session value with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, session

Is it possible to read a session value with Javascript?

For example, if I assigned a value into a session in PHP:

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "ABC Message";
```

Is it possible to read `$_SESSION['msg']` with Javascript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$_SESSION is a server-side construct. You would need to store that variable in $_COOKIE to be able to access it client-side.

Comment: Why is this being voted up? harto's solution proves it untrue.

Comment: Yes agreed, but it doesn't answer the question and is in fact presenting misleading information.

Comment: How is this misleading? You cannot read a session variable with javascript. You either have to stuff the value into a cookie, which javascript could access, or have it rendered out to the page itself. That is not very secure.

Comment: Cookies are no more secure, they're easily visible in most browsers.

Comment: Right. Shouldn't have mentioned security. My point was that $_SESSION is not a client-side construct. Either stash the value in a client-side construct ($_COOKIE, render it out in the HTML), or make an AJAX request to a service that will return that value from your server-side session.

Comment: If you use a cookie to store session variable, you can have a big security issue in your code. If i change cookie data with your email?

Comment: Which is only important if the value you are saving needs to be secure.

Answer (score 40):

A very simple way is to generate the JavaScript with some PHP code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo 'var msg = "'.json_encode($_SESSION['msg']).'";';
</script>
```

Comment: If $_SESSION['msg'] stores sensitive information, outputting to an unencrypted page is a security risk, and HTTPS should be used.

Comment: but by doing so you expose the value directly and it's accessible from the console and can be modified. What if you need to get a sensible information like a privilege_type id and you don't want your user to be able to change it : you need to access such value at runtime from a private methode and never store it to use it later.

Comment: If this gets cached then you'll see your world burn. That's why I prefer cookie method which is accepted answer.

Comment: Wow. There's a good answer and 2 good constructive points. My question based on this specific answer and these comments is, what if I just want to check if the user is in fact logged in? Just a quick true or false check returned in JSON as presented in this reply, regarding a successful login that has already happen in a different page written in PHP Only? Then it's OK?

Answer (score 6):

.. Or you can use ajax to retrive your server side session value into you client-side   javascript.`
(quick, dirty and untested example,  using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax))

**Javascript Side:**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        eval( html ); /// UGLY NASTY YOU MUST VALIDATE YOUR INPUTS... JUST AN EXAMPLE
      }
    });
```

**PHP side  test.php:**

```
echo 'var myData = "'. $_SESSION['msg'].'"';
```

Answer (score 3):

If this helps anyone, those examples returned `null`, so I just used:

```
<?php session_start();
   $msg = $_SESSION['msg'];
?>

<script>
   <?php echo "var msg = '" .$msg . "'"; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Not really answering the question

Comment: I see you -1'd me.  The question is "Is it possible to read $_SESSION['msg'] with Javascript?" 

my answer uses javascript to access a php variable, in case that helped anyone.  Your comment is that my answer did not resolve the question.  You are wrong.

Comment: Read your answer once again. The question was is it possible to read session variables. The answer is "No", but there's a workaround helpful in some situations. You didn't state that. Also some code formatting would be nice. var msg = '<?php echo $msg; ?>'; looks much better than joining the whole javascript line in php. I'm sorry, but this doesn't look like the answer to the question asked. Try improving it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>";
alert(foo);
</script>
```

Comment: the alert message returns <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To make an even easier example of Luis Melgratti´s answer you can just return a json encoded value from PHP and use jQuery to parse it, like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#some_button")
    .click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "get_session.php",
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(result)
        {
            var session_credentials = $.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(session_credentials);
        });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
//get_session.php
<?php
    session_start();
    echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

I believe there are even more answers on a similar SO-thread here: [how-to-access-php-session-variables-from-jquery-function-in-a-js-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365738/how-to-access-php-session-variables-from-jquery-function-in-a-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

May It Works :

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

getCookie('PHPSESSID');
```