# Usung java script how can i pass a variable to a $_SESSION[''] object?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In a java function I want to pass a variable over to $_SESSION.
I have tried to do this like the following ... $_SESSION['ID'] = document.getElementById('lbxDates').value;

This does not work for me, so if anyone knows how i should approach this in a proper manner any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetID(){$_SESSION['ID']=document.getElementById('lbxDates').value;} 
</script>
```

Comment: You can't.  By the time the JS gets to the browser to execute, the PHP has already executed on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: If your session data is not secret, manage it with javascript... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

The interaction between Javascript and PHP is one way, meaning you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('lbxDates').value = <?= $_SESSION['ID'] ?>;
```

but not this:

```
$_SESSION['ID'] = document.getElementById('lbxDates').value;
```

To accomplish what you're looking for, you'll need to make use of XMLHTTP requests (or if you use JQuery, AJAX). Here's an example of someone accomplishing this:
[Can i set session variables when posting data via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411019/can-i-set-session-variables-when-posting-data-via-javascript)

Comment: Ok understood, I will try this out from the link and see how i get on thank you very much!