# Cant access sessions in php that is set in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a session in jquery using following code

```
$.session.set("name","xyz");
```

Now when i try to access the session 'name' in php i cant

```
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: I've never heard of `$.session`, is that a plugin?  Where does it write its data?  Unless it's making AJAX calls to server-side pages you've added which interact with the session, it's not going to have anything to do with your server-side session.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible because they are different context.

PHP doc
http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.session.php

jQuery doc
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/session/

What you are probably looking for (the answer)
[Read session value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754761/read-session-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

$.session.set stores the data in the browser something like a local storage which is accessible across multiple pages from the same site during a browser session. This data stored and accessible on the browser.

But a PHP session variable is stored and accessible in the server. So you cannot access a value stored in jquery session from a PHP session. Hope it clears your confusion